# How to add Meta Keywords

Tags: home, meta-tags, ce-1.9.2.1

I'm sure that I setted the meta keywords for my website. I added them to CMS home page and to `Configuration>Design>Head>default keywords`, but if I analyze my site with an online SEO tool, it appears without meta keywords. How can I solve?

Comment: Goto cms->page->select your home page -> in left panel select Meta data->ther you have to add Keyword

Comment: are you still getting the wrong meta keywords?

Comment: @Kothari I already did that, as you can read in my question "I added them to CMS home page", but unfortunately the analysis tool continued to say that there aren't keywords.